# Compute the distance between elements in a bi-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matrix, ecmascript-6

Having the following input string: `923857614`

This is represented into a matrix like this:

```
9 2 3
8 5 7
6 1 4
```

Having a moving sequence like this: 423692, this means that we start in point 4, we move to 2, then to 3, then to 6, then to 9 and finally to 2.

It must be computed the length of the road. At beginning it starts from 0, if the next step is adjacent to the current one, add 1, if it isn't adjacent, add 2.

How I tried to do it:

```
function computeRoadLength(keypad, movingSequence) {
  // build the matrix
 const arr = [[keypad[0], keypad[1], keypad[2]],
              [keypad[3], keypad[4], keypad[5]], 
              [keypad[6], keypad[7], keypad[8]]];
  let roadLength = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < movingSequence.length; i++) {
    // some way to compute the distance here
    if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) roadLength = roadLength + 1;
    if (arr[i] < arr[i+1]) roadLength = roadLength + 2;
  }

  return roadLength;
}

computeRoadLength(923857614, 423692); // 2 + 1 + 2  + 2  + 1 = 8, should return 8
```

Comment: There are a bunch of problems here, including the fact that you're reassigning a `const` and the array is almost certainly not structured the way you want it to be.

Comment: Not really, you're still overriding `const roadLength`

Comment: Go ahead and put a sample array in there and make it a demo snippet.

Comment: What do you mean by `point`? Do you mean the index of the array? So point 4 would be index 4 of the `keypad`, and thus `5`? Or is it 1-based, so point 4 would be 8?

Comment: it is where the value 4 is, so position is 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a different approach by using an object of positions of all keypad values and take the absolute delta of the positions.

For adding to `movingSequence` add one or max two.

```js
function computeRoadLength(keypad, movingSequence) {
    const positions = {};
    
    for (let i = 0; i < keypad.length; i++) {
        positions[keypad[i]] = [Math.floor(i / 3), i % 3];
    }
    
    let roadLength = 0,
        last = positions[movingSequence[0]];

    for (let i = 1; i < movingSequence.length; i++) {
        const
            item = positions[movingSequence[i]],
            sum = Math.abs(last[0] - item[0]) + Math.abs(last[1] - item[1]);
                
        roadLength += Math.min(sum, 2);        
        last = item;
    }

    return roadLength;
}

console.log(computeRoadLength('923857614', '423692')); // 2 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 8
```